# Separate binding for keys with shift

Tags: emacs, clipboard

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.1.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 and want to use something similar to the emacs clipboard settings described [here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/CopyAndPaste#toc4), but I want to keep the default behavior and get the alternate one by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>. I mean something like this

```
;;; these are the defaults anyway
(global-set-key "\C-w" 'kill-region)
(global-set-key "\M-w" 'yank-pop)
(global-set-key "\C-y" 'clipboard-yank)

;;; these should be the clipboard-aware versions
(global-set-key "\C-W" 'clipboard-kill-region)
(global-set-key "\S-\M-w" 'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
(global-set-key "\C-Y" 'clipboard-yank)
```

But only `\S-\M-w` works well, while using `\C-W` works exactly like `C-w`. I tried also `\S-\C-w`, but this ends up with "Invalid modifier in string".

How can I bind <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> separately from <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-w") 'clipboard-kill-region)
(global-set-key (kbd "M-W")   'clipboard-kill-ring-save)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-y") 'clipboard-yank)
```